# Cant log in to Mirth 3.8.1 after upgarde

Tags: authentication, mirth

I recently upgraded  Mirth to version 3.8.1.
Since the upgrade  I have been unable to log in to the Web dashboard nor the Connect Administrator.
I have tried  my previous  credentials for the previous ver and the default admin/admin.

I was wondering has anyone else experienced similar issues?

Additional:
When I try to connect using Mirth Connect Server:

> ERROR 2020-03-10 13:47:08,925 [Main Server Thread]
>   com.mirth.connect.server.Mirt h: http.port port is already in use:
>   8082 ERROR 2020-03-10 13:47:08,925 [Main Server Thread]
>   com.mirth.connect.server.Mirt h: https.port port is already in use:
>   8443

But looking at port 8443 it appears to be listening:
C:\windows\system32>netstat -a | findstr 8443
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8443           LAB003708:0            LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:8443              LAB003708:0            LISTENING

I have checked the

> mirth-cli-config

file and the username and password is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After allot of troubleshooting it appeared that although the Mirth 3.8.1 installer detected the previous version it had not removed the Mirth Connect Server ver 3.7, so when I launched Mirth 3.8.1 there appeared  to be two Mirth connections to same port and there was a conflict.

Running a combination of manually deleting and using the MS uninstall program fro Mirth 3.7, then reinstalling Mirth 3.8.1 worked.

Hopefully this might be useful for someone with same issue.